# Disable notifications when other audio is playing

Tags: notifications, audio, music

I have a Sony Xperia Z1 with 4.4.2 Kitkat

Is possible disable the sound of the notifications when I listen music or doing something?

I'm watching a video of youtube, listen music with headphones ( device is silent), etc. but when telegram or whatsapp receive a notification it sounds. If i disable the media volume i can't listen the video or the music

I know that other devices have the option to disable notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can goto `Settings->Sound->Volumes->Ringtone&Notification` and reduce the volume.

(or) You can press the volume down button to disable notification and then start listening to media.